# Why isn't meiosis II called mitosis (as the chromosome number doesn't half)?

Tags: meiosis, mitosis

> **Meiosis**: a type of cell division that results in four daughter cells each with half the number of chromosomes of the parent cell, as in the production of gametes and plant spores.
>
> **Mitosis:** a type of cell division that results in two daughter cells each having the same number and kind of chromosomes as the parent nucleus, typical of ordinary tissue growth.

After meosis II we have the same number of chromosomes as before. So why isn't meiosis II called mitosis instead?

Answer (score 5):

Well, in my opinion, the entirety of the meiosis is a process (reproduction of sex cell) in which two levels of division occur, it's all kind of one process. Though meiosis II may seem to have many similarities with mitosis, meiosis II can only occur with sex cells, to my understanding that is the main factor which differentiates meiosis I and II from mitosis. Furthermore, regardless of the similarities, to call meiosis II the same as 'mitosis' (whilst meiosis II is still in the entirety of the meiosis process) is not only confusing but impractical. I'm sure, though, that somewhere along the line there are several detailed differences between the technicality behind the cellular division in mitosis as in meiosis II. But, don't listen solely to my answer, that's just my opinion since your question is subjective to my personal opinion...